# Award publicity badges for sharing Tag Wikis

Tags: feature-request, badges, tag-wiki, publicity-badges

This is part 2 of [**Highlighting the Tag Wikis**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179500/200868).

---

Currently, there are three badges (Announcer, Booster and Publicist) that encourage sharing questions (and implicitly, answers). I suggest that these should be awarded for sharing a tag wiki page as well. The conditions for tag wikis could either be the same or have slight variations. As tag wikis have view counters associated with them, a part of the implementation required for this feature is already present.

#### Why?

As discussed in [Part 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179500/200868), tag wikis are an invaluable resource, especially for new beta communities. Newer sites have a much lower volume of questions, but not any lack of expertise. Hence, there is the possibility for a lot of active wiki curation. These wikis' function as a representation of the expertise that exists in the community and keeps users engaged by enabling knowledge-sharing.

Awarding badges for sharing tag wikis will provide incentive to users to share the wikis. This will encourage others to contribute and to curate, similar to how users participate in asking and answering questions.