# Tag Wiki vs Community Wiki

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, community-wiki, tag-wiki

I spend a lot of time on Stack Overflow answering questions about date, time and time zones.  (This is somewhat of a favorite subject of mine.)

Over the past many months, I have been improving and expanding the [timezone](/questions/tagged/timezone) tag wiki [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info). It's very useful, and I constantly reference it in answers and comments.

However, I'm starting to think that I have unintentionally misused this part of the system. Is this an appropriate use of a tag wiki? Or should I migrate the content to a community wiki question and answer?

Should there be a limit imposed on the size of a tag wiki? Or at least some guidelines about the depth and breadth of the subject there?

Part of my concern is that I want others to feel free to add or edit it, but I don't think they do because there are no rankings or credit given (other than the [Research Assistant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188732#188732) badge).

Also, I have to point so often at it - I wish it would just come up towards the top of search results for questions about time zones. There is already the [Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices) community wiki post, but it is very broad and covers all kinds of things, not just time zones. Should there be another like that? Or should it stay as a tag wiki?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: This is a perfectly good Tag Wiki; I only wish more looked like this one.  See [tag:php](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info), [tag:C++](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) and [tag:android](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info) for other examples where tag wikis are used to good effect.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the confirmation.  I thought maybe I was doing something wrong since there are *very* many questions that are easily answered with "see the tag wiki".

Comment: That's kinda the whole point. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I'm starting to think that I have unintentionally misused this part of the system. Is this an appropriate use of a tag wiki?

Most certainly, yes. Tag wikis are supposed to cover a fair bit about the subject in question, reference good questions and answers, and point to useful external links, as well as have book/reference lists wherever possible. So, referencing tag wikis in answers is entirely appropriate. In fact, I recommend it.

> Or should I migrate the content to a community wiki question and answer?

While I understand why this may seem a better option, it isnt. Such content is collaborative, ever changing, and consists of information that would not be suitable in a Q&A. The Tag wikis are designed to hold exactly this information.

I understand that tag wikis do have some problems such as searchability and visibility, [concerns that I have voiced previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179500/200868). The appropriate approach to this issue is not to circumvent the system but rather to work towards improving it and making it a usable resource for all users. You may work towards this by suggesting a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or starting a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).

> Should there be a limit imposed on the size of a tag wiki?

There is a 30k character limit, IIRC.

> Or at least some guidelines about the depth and breadth of the subject there?

This is something that is missing as well. I have brought it up on [Reverse Engineering Meta](https://reverseengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/97/189) and there was a bit of discussion on the subject. This list of topics mentioned there is pretty comprehensive.

> Part of my concern is that I want others to feel free to add or edit it, but I don't think they do because there are no rankings or credit given (other than the Research Assistant badge).

This is not entirely correct. There is a +2 for suggesting an edit that gets accepted other than the badge. However, these are not sufficient motivation for working on a resource that gets used barely, if ever. This takes us back to the issue of searchability and visibility.

Also, I believe, that there is a need to [give incentive for sharing the tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188197/200868). This will motivate others to contribute to the tag wikis and may result in interesting dynamics between domain communities on large sites.

> Also, I have to point so often at it - I wish it would just come up towards the top of search results for questions about time zones.

[Work to turn this into a reality!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179500/200868)

Comment: I agree with you wholeheartedly.  Thanks for the detailed response!

Comment: I also fail to see how a question regarding only time zones would be on topic, even if it is community wiki.

Comment: @ColeJohnson - There are *many* questions about time zones in computing.  Most are language or platform specific, but many are not.  It's one of those things that affects everyone but somehow the vast majority of folks don't understand how they work.  When those people are programmers, that lack of knowledge leads to application logic errors.